# Yii2 left join query with not null condition

Tags: php, yii2

I have a books and book borrow table and i want to query all borrowed books that is where borrowed books is not null.

The table structure is

```
tbl_books
   id
   name
```

then borrowed books

```
tbl_borrowed_books
    id
    book_id
    borrowed_at
```

So in my query i have

```
$query = TblBooks::find()->leftJoin('tbl_borrowed_books','tbl_borrowed_books.book_id = tbl_books.id')->all();
```

SO now i want to add a condition where i want to get all the books with a record in `tbl_borrowed_books`

How do i check for not null

SO something like

```
   $query = TblBooks::find()->leftJoin('tbl_borrowed_books','tbl_borrowed_books.book_id = tbl_books.id')
  ->where('<>','') //stuck here on adding the not null condition
  ->all();
```

Comment: Is there any reason you are fixated on `LEFT JOIN`? `INNER JOIN` returns only records that exists in both tables. It's basically exactly what you are looking for, isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you insist on using `LEFT JOIN` then you can check any column from the second table that can't have `NULL` as valid value. You can use for example it's primary key or foreign key column.

```php
 $query = TblBooks::find()
    ->leftJoin(
        'tbl_borrowed_books',
        'tbl_borrowed_books.book_id = tbl_books.id'
    )->where(['not', 'tbl_borrowed_books.book_id', NULL])
    ->all();
```

But it's better to use `INNER JOIN` because it only returns records where matching record exist in both tables. So it does exactly the same thing as what `WHERE tbl_borrowed_books.book_id IS NOT NULL` would do.

```php
$query = TblBooks::find()
    ->innerJoin(
        'tbl_borrowed_books',
        'tbl_borrowed_books.book_id = tbl_books.id'
    )->all();
```

Answer (score -1):

More `ActiveRecord` based solution to get intersected borrowed books:

```
$borrowedBooks = TblBooks::find()->joinWith('borrowedBooks', true, 'inner join')->all();
```